# Sonata admin highlight Field Message

Tags: sonata-admin

Concept : Admin wants to know how many people use bad words (swear words) in the review listing and admin enters some of the words which are commonly used by the customer.

I am using sonata admin as my backend. I am displaying list like below with the direct listMapper.

```
$listMapper->add('message');
```

In my Message column there is a message like: "I am really Happy today".

And i have list of words in array which i need to highlight in the listing page.

[image]

Now in the listing page i need Happy as a highlight because it is in the array which i have, concept like swear words.

In the front end twig file i need same functionality which i need to make it *** instead of swear words which i achieve by making extension.

```
{{ review.message|truncate(150, true, ' ...')|check_word_exist_in_array_and_replace(swearWordsList,'***') }}
```

Extension Is:

```
new \Twig_SimpleFilter('check_word_exist_in_array_and_replace', array($this, 'checkWordExistInArrayAndReplace')),

public function checkWordExistInArrayAndReplace($string,$array,$replace_str)
{
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        $string =  str_ireplace($element,$replace_str,$string);            
    }
    return $string;
}
```